# How do I reload/refresh the contacts birthday's calendar in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-contacts

I recently removed a number of contacts from Gmail but their birthday's still show up in my contacts birthday's calendar I subscribe to.

I unsubscribed/resubscribed to the calendar but the birthdays for contacts I've removed are still there.

Is there a way to reload the calendar so it matches my updated contacts list?

Comment: Did you delete the contacts or just remove them from the My Contacts group?

Comment: I actually deleted them from Contacts.app on my iPod touch and it synced with Google Sync which was setup on my touch. It's been a couple weeks and the changes still haven't been committed to my Google Calendar.

However if I delete from the contacts manager in Gmail from a web browser changes are shown immediately.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an overnight process. A couple months ago I added a whole bunch of anniversaries and birthdays and they didn't actually appear in the calendar until the next day. Same when I removed some.

Comment: I found it's immediate since when I deleted from the Gmail contact manager changes were immediate on the Calendar side for birthdays. I think it had to do with deleting contacts from my iPod and having Google Sync not send those changes back properly from my iOS device.

Comment: Yes, the "overnight" thing is an inference, not a fact. Based on my observations today, I think like @Thardus that this is not an overnight process, but rather one that has some zombie characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out while doing some cleaning in my Google Contacts.

For those who are wondering how to fix the problem I was having do the following:

- Export Google contacts to a file on your PC
- Delete all contacts from your Google account
- Restore the file you just exported.

When I did that it refreshed/reloaded all my contacts and cleaned up the zombie entries.

Comment: I want to add to this answer: Today, I had the same issue. I made a large update on birthdays that did not seem to propagate to the "Birthdays" calendar that Google automatically creates. I deleted a *single* contact, and this seems to have had the effect of updating the index or something. I did not need to add all contacts for this to take effect. It could be that the process that generates birthdays is only triggered when there is an addition/removal of a contact. Any addition/removal might trigger it.